# Espacio entre letras de algunas palabras en listados de código en lyx

Tags: lyx

Al pasar a PDF un documento sobre programación que estoy creando en Lyx, me aparecen unos molestos espacios entre letras en algunas palabras cuando utilizo listas de código para insertar algunos trozos de programación.

Por ejemplo ---> fmt . P r i n t

Las letras de la palabra Print están separadas entre sí por espacios. Esto es fatal para copiar/pegar estos pedazos de código en un IDE, por ejemplo. En la configuración de listado de código de Lyx he añadido la opción "showstringspaces=false" pero no consigo nada.

¿pueden decirme como puedo quitar estos molestos espacios para que todas las letras de cada palabra en las listas de código aparezcan juntas entre sí?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

me contesto a mi mismo. Poniendo la opción columns=fullflexible o columns=flexible en la configuración de las listas de código se soluciona